# Swift 3 HTTP Request post with parameter error JSON format

Tags: json, swift, post, parameters, httprequest

I'm trying to send a http request using swift 3

it started like this with 2.3 and it worked well

```
func addBill(){
    let parameter:[String:AnyObject] =
        [
            "app":"mpbid",
            "token":userDefault.getToken()!,
            "ver":1,
            "data":
            [
                [
                    "productId":String(self.product!.productId!),
                    "customerId":self.nomorTeleponField.text!
                ]
            ]
        ]
    HTTPRequest.addBill(parameter, startRequest: {          

        }) { (responseType, message, data) in

            if responseType == HTTPRequest.responseType.Success{
                if let status = data!["status"] as? String where status == "OK"{
                    if let datas = data!["data"] as? NSArray where datas.count > 0{


                        let errorResponse = datas[0]["errorStatus"] as! String

                       (errorResponse.characters.count) ")

                        if errorResponse.characters.count == 0 {
                            self.inquiryData = datas[0] as? [String:AnyObject]

                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showConfirmation", sender: self)
```

it succeed with a status 200 OK

but after swift 3 migration, i've turned the source code to this

```
func addBill(){
    let parameter:[String:AnyObject] =
        [
            "app":"mpbid" as AnyObject,
            "token":userDefault.getToken()! as AnyObject,
            "ver":1 as AnyObject,
            "data":
            [
                [
                    "productId":String(describing: self.product!.productId!),
                    "customerId":self.nomorTeleponField.text!,
                    "productCode":String(describing: self.product!.productCode!)
                ],
            ] as AnyObject,
    ]

    HTTPRequest.addBill(parameter, startRequest: {

        }) { (responseType, message, data) in               

            if responseType == HTTPRequest.responseType.success{
                if let status = data!["status"] as? String, status == "OK"{
                    if let datas = data!["data"] as? NSArray, datas.count > 0{
                        let errorResponse = (datas[0] as! [String:AnyObject])["errorStatus"] as! String(errorResponse.characters.count) ")

                        if errorResponse.characters.count == 0 {
                            self.inquiryData = datas[0] as? [String:AnyObject]
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showConfirmation", sender: self)
```

It gave me status 500 internal server error
I guess I got wrong JSON format on sending the parameter using swift 3, any help would be really appreciated... thanks before

Comment: It may be due to extra parameter "productCode" you are passing compared to previous set of parameters.

Comment: I'd also suggest manually converting it to JSON, and printing it out, and see if there's anything curious. E.g. `let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .prettyPrinted); let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!; print("\(string)")`

Comment: Or perhaps watch the Swift 2.3 rendition in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) and compare to the same request from your Swift 3 code...

Comment: Tried that and the JSON format looks fine tho :/